# Apply text to hover based on condition in AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs

How can I select specific text to appear in hover based on logic using angularjs?  For example, I have a value and if the class equals 'warning' I want a specific hover message, if the class equals 'success' I want a different hover message to appear.

My logic is to write a function that says if color = success hover = this, if color = warning hover = that, if color = error hover = something else.
Any advice?

```js
      getColor = function() {
            var data = 88;

            if(data < 75){
                return "losses-success";
            }else
            if(data >=75 && data < 90){
                return "losses-warning";
            }else
            if(data > 90){
                return "losses-error";
            }
        };
```

```css
.losses-success{
    display: inline-block!important;
    width: 8px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: green;
}
.losses-warning{
    display: inline-block!important;
    width: 8px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.losses-error{
    display: inline-block!important;
    width: 8px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="cTotal" class="losses-tooltip" ng-class="getColor()">
  <span class="tooltiptext"> </span>
  <span class="block"><sup>$</sup>
    <strong class="amount">{{loss}}</strong></span>
</div>
```

Comment: How is the data passed to the action? How are you going to trigger the action?

Comment: Yes, the approach you're thinking about would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your classes and messages are fixed, I think it's better to return an object with the class and the message:

```
return {
     ngclass: "losses-success",
     message: "some text"
}
```

Than you can use the class property in ng-class and show the message related to that property.

```
<div id="cTotal" class="losses-tooltip" ng-class="getColor().ngclass">
     {{getColor().message}}
</div>
```

I don't like this approach so much, because the getColor() function is called on every angular cycle. And the getColor().ngclass syntax seems to be weird to me.

I prefer to set the object in a controller, and update the values when it's needed. If you can't control when the class and message would be updated, you can choose the first approach. If you is able to control this, you can simply:

```
function getColor(value) {
    //put you logic
    //
    $scope.myObj = {
         ngclass: "anyclass",
         message: "any message"
    }
}
```

And in your template:

```
<div id="cTotal" class="losses-tooltip" ng-class="myObj.ngclass">
     {{myObj.message}}
</div>
```

Note that in this second approach you need to call your getColor function to update the values in myObj, so you have a better performance.

In the first approach the function is called on every cycle, so the values are updated every time (you don't need to call the function explicitly in your controller to update the value). So, in this case you need to be careful about the performance of your application.

Comment: To complete, your approach seems to work, but I think it's not the best way to do this, because you would need one more function. You can do this simply in one step, like show in the answer. So, you can have a better performance.

Comment: It's seems to be weird, but it works.... This is the reason why I said that I prefer the second approach. I write this plunker showing the first solution working: https://plnkr.co/edit/0OePOxiyaH3h3Z7m9oFE

Comment: OH. I see... *"ngclass" is just a terrible property name*... I thought you were using ngClass in ng-class. Either way... this works but is likely far away from how it would be applied practically.

Comment: Yes, this should be avoided in a real application. The second approach is better in this situation.

Comment: @L.Figueredo, thanks, your solution was just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really write Angular.js... so this isn't the best way - I'm sure... but it's more of an example of how you should create a jsFiddle - and work out the problem more before asking: http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/U3pVM/33739/

### app setup ( + controller)

```
var app = angular.module('ExampleApp', [/* no dependencies */]);

app.controller('ExampleCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.crapList = [57, 94, 72, 20];

  $scope.getColor = function(inputData) {
    if (inputData > 90) {
      return 'error';
    }
    if (inputData > 70) {
      return 'warning';
    }
    return 'success';
  };
});
```

### template

```
<main ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <h1>Example</h1>
  <section ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">

    <ul class="crap-list">
      <li class="crap" ng-class='getColor(crap)'
        ng-repeat="crap in crapList">

        <span>{{crap}}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </section>
</main>
```

### styles

```
.crap {
  /* display: inline-block!important; 
  if you have to add !important... then you are doing something very wrong further up your style-sheet*/
  /* width: 8px;  what? this is a bad idea */
  /* height: 20px;  the content should determine it's height */
  margin-top: .2rem;
  padding: .5rem;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 2px;
}
.crap.success {
  background: green;
}
.crap.warning {
  background: orange;
}
.crap.error {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: PS - If you're just getting started with angular.js / maybe you should choose a different path. That time is over.